# MySQL tables full! 'update_cache' and 'block' both, presumably others

Tags: caching, database

I inherited a D7 site. It's plagued with error messages that I can't quite figure out how to fix.

During my debugging process, I ran into some PDOExceptions where it says my MySQL tables are FULL! The site isn't launched yet, and there should be NO WAY that the tables should be full.

Some random things I've noticed

- the `update_cache` table is full
- the `blocks` table is full
- none of the `cache_*` tables actually clear out when I run "flush caches"

  - related to this, there's a PDOException that gets squelched when I try to "flush caches." It can only be viewed from the Apache `error_log`, and it appears that it prevents the menus from being rebuilt (a problem I noticed trying to install a new module)

Does anyone have a clue as to why my MySQL tables would be filling up / why Drupal can't clear them out?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Run `df -h` on the machine - how much room is left on the hard drive that contains MySQL? MySQL tables can be in excess of a terabyte in size (depending on engine and other factors), so it's pretty likely the constraint is coming from elsewhere

Comment: If you could add the output of `df -h` to the question, I think that will help. It's really hard to say why they are filling up without knowing how much they are filling up. There is a big difference between 500mb's and 500gb's.

Comment: Yep it definitely looks like it's all being used. I've got /dev/xvda1 at 7.8gb / 7.9gb. But, I have no idea why it would be eating up that much space!! This site isn't that old, and there's definitely not enough users to add that amount of data...

Comment: How big are the cache tables?

Comment: @Steven I can only assume by "big" you mean how many rows? If you're asking # of bytes you'll need to walk me thru that, I'm PHP programmer not very good at being a SysAdmin. Most of the cache tables have < 100 rows in them... there are a few that have over 200 rows. In fact, in all of my MySQL database, there is not even a single table that has over 10K rows - it doesn't seem like the DB would be taking up that much data?

Comment: @tigertrussell Search the drive for an `ibdata1` file (MySQL's flat InnoDB storage file) - how big is that one?

Comment: @Clive That file is ~300MB. I was able to track down the culprit of my full drive to be the devel_querylog, which had a ton of 128MB text files. I've removed them, and now I've got 3.4 GB available.

Comment: Try restarting the MySQL daemon, that normally flushes it

Comment: @Clive I had gone ahead and deleted them all manually. Strictly speaking, this problem has been solved. However, I only discovered this problem trying to solve another one (you're also in that thread). I'll pick it up on the other  thread for organization's sake.